# Using Atlassian Bamboo CI with Scala Playframework 2.X

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, bamboo

I am having a difficult time finding the steps necessary to set up Bamboo for continuous integration of my Scala based Play framework application. I have written my tests in specs2, but Bamboo doesn't support it out of the box. It does support junit tests. I read somewhere that I could convert the output to junit, but I can no longer find a way to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add the following to your sbt build file to generate JUnit output for your Specs.

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("junitxml", "console")
```

Then you can define the [SBT Task](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.sbt.bamboo-sbt-plugin) to execute the tests.

[image: SBT Task setup]

Comment: Thank you! I had tried adding this line before, but I guess I didn't reload my project or something. It's working now!

Comment: seeing as that plugin has been deleted is there another way to run sbt in bamboo?

Comment: Yes, run it as command https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/custom-command-executable-289277045.html